# How can I link my dropdown list values to a PHP request variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

sorry as I am very beginner the question may be silly but I am trying out a PHP script I found from an article.

If assume that the same files from the article is used but the difference is that I have added a dropdown in index.html, I am unsure on how I can edit the code to make it replace test-data.json in ChatBot.php with my dropdown menu's value. To be specific it actually will be a radio button value for folder name + dropdown for file name.

I believe I will need to remove the part of test-data.json in ChatBot.php and somehow make the changes in requestmanager.php so the JSON file gets processed once clicked on Send, right? Any ideas on what can be done here? I mostly am aiming to do front-end on my part so this article was ok for for a project I am working on but I need it to be able to choose specific JSON files depending on the dropdown menu's value.

I have tried to play around with AJAX requests a bit but have pretty much deleted all the changes I made for this as I was pretty much on the wrong path.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello A.I. Bot!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script type="module">
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

            document.querySelector(".sendMessage").addEventListener('click', (event) => {

                event.currentTarget.classList.add('is-loading');
                event.currentTarget.disabled = true;

                document.querySelector(".result").parentElement.classList.add("is-hidden");
                document.querySelector(".error").parentElement.classList.add("is-hidden");

                let currHour = new Date();

                const userMsgTemplate = `<div class="columns">
                                        <div class="column is-one-third"></div>
                                        <div class="column">
                                            <div class="notification is-success">
                                                <h6 class="subtitle is-6">${currHour.getHours() + ":" + currHour.getMinutes()}</h6>
                                                ${document.querySelector(".message").value}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>`


                let chatBox = document.querySelector(".messageHistory");

                chatBox.innerHTML += userMsgTemplate;
                chatBox.scrollIntoView(false);

                const payload = JSON.stringify({
                    "message": document.querySelector(".message").value
                });

                document.querySelector(".message").value = "";

                fetch('requestmanager.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: payload,
                }).then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {

                        let currHour = new Date();

                        data.responseMessage = data.responseMessage.replace("\n", "<br>");

                        let aiMsgTemplate = `<div class="columns">
                                                <div class="column">
                                                    <div class="notification is-info">
                                                        <h6 class="subtitle is-6">${currHour.getHours() + ":" + currHour.getMinutes()}</h6>
                                                        ${data.responseMessage}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="column is-one-third"></div>
                                            </div>`

                        chatBox.innerHTML += aiMsgTemplate;
                        chatBox.scrollIntoView(false);

                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    }).finally(() => {
                        document.querySelector(".sendMessage").classList.remove('is-loading');
                        document.querySelector(".sendMessage").disabled = false;
                    });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns  box">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="column has-text-centered">
                            <h1 class="title">
                                Hello A.I. Bot!
                            </h1>
<div id="radio" class="radio-group">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="tos" onclick="showDropdown('generalDropdown')"> <span style="color:white;">General</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="tos/agreements" onclick="showDropdown('folder1Dropdown')"> <span style="color:white;">Folder 1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="category" value="tos/policies" onclick="showDropdown('folder2Dropdown')"> <span style="color:white;">Folder 2</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div id="generalDropdown" class="dropdown">
    <select>
        <option value="opt1.json">Option 1 in root path</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="folder1Dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <select>
        <option value="opt1.json">Option 1 in folder 1</option>
        <option value="opt2.json">Option 2 in folder 1</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="folder2Dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <select>
        <option value="opt.json">Option 1 in folder 2</option>
        <option value="opt2.json">Option 2 in folder 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="card-content" style="height:600px;overflow:auto;flex-grow: 1;flex-shrink: 1;">
                                <div class="content messageHistory">


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="column">
                            <input class="input message" type="text" placeholder="Type your message">
                        </div>
                        <div class="column is-narrow">
                            <button class="button is-info sendMessage">
                                Send
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="columns box is-hidden">
                <div class="column result"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="columns box is-hidden">
                <div class="column notification is-danger error has-text-centered">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

On the index.html above, radio and dropdown options can be seen which is the values I wish to be replaced with the JSON file in ChatBot.php's $jsonSampleData variable

requestmanager.php

```
<?php

// Include the definition of the ChatBot class to be used for our query.
require("ChatBot.php");

// Decode the parameters received from the index.html file and store them in the $paramsFetch array.
$paramsFetch = json_decode(
    file_get_contents("php://input"),
    true
);

$ChatBot = new ChatBot();

// Send the message to our AI.
$resMessage = $ChatBot->sendMessage($paramsFetch["message"]);

// Next, we return the response in JSON format and exit the execution.
$jsonResponse = json_encode(array("responseMessage" => $resMessage));
echo $jsonResponse;
exit;
```

ChatBot.php

```
<?php

/**
 * ChatBot Class
 */
class ChatBot
{
    /**
     * @var string The authorization token for the API
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * @var string The endpoint URL for the OpenAI.com API
     */
    private $endpoint;

    /**
     * ChatBot constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // This token is not real, in case you were thinking what I'm thinking...
        $this->authorization = 'sk-';
        $this->endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
    }

    /**
     * Send a message to the API and return the response.
     *
     * @param string $message The message to send
     * @return string The response message
     * @throws Exception If there is an error in sending the message via cURL
     */
    public function sendMessage(string $message): string
    {
        // Read sample data from our JSON file
        $jsonSampleData = file_get_contents("test-data.json");

        // Prepare data for sending
        $data = [
            'messages' => [
                [
                    'role' => 'system',
                    'content' => 'You are a kind and helpful customer service member at a PC components store. 
                    If the user asks how to buy, refer them to our website at https://medium.com/winkhosting.
                    If the user asks anything about CPUs or RAM, use exclusively the cpu or ram input in the following JSON string to suggest options:' . $jsonSampleData
                ],
                [
                    'role' => 'user',
                    'content' => $message
                ],
            ],
            'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
        ];

        // Set headers for the API request
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->authorization,
        ];

        // Send the request to the API using cURL
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for errors in the API response
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            $error = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception('Error sending the message: ' . $error);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        // Parse the API response
        $arrResult = json_decode($response, true);
        $resultMessage = $arrResult["choices"][0]["message"]["content"];

        // Return the response message
        return $resultMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Without seeing how and what you already tried it's very hard to help you here.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You need to provide the latter, directly inside your question, and not just refer us to external sites.

Comment: Links to external tutorials / code files etc aren't allowed - they can change or disappear in future, making the question useless to other readers. Plus we don't know precisely what changes you've made, as you stated you had done some. As above please [edit] your question with a [mre] of the specific issue you're having (which may or may not involve a dump of the entire codebase), and a clear description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have removed the link and included the code instead with the radio and dropdown

Comment: Would the edited version help perhaps @Sitethief ?

Comment: TL;DR; - too much code ~ it appears from the wording of the question that you want to know how to use the value from a `select` menu in your AJAX request. I see a `select` menu with `opt1.json` and `opt2.json` as values - do you wish to send the contents of these (.json files) in your  request to the chatbot?

Comment: You'd need to amend the JS at `const payload = JSON.stringify({ "message": document.querySelector(".message").value });` so it includes the selected radio and dropdown options in the uploaded JSON, then change `$ChatBot->sendMessage($paramsFetch["message"])` to pass in an extra parameter contaning the filename (which you'll need to derive from the submitted JSON values) and amend `public function sendMessage(string $message): string {$jsonSampleData = file_get_contents("test-data.json");` to accept that parameter and then use it in the file_get_contents call.

Comment: Yes, I wish the selected .json file to be sent to the chatbot to be added next to the text in ChatBot.php file in this part:

    $data = [
            'messages' => [
                [
                    'role' => 'system',
                    'content' =>

Comment: Thanks for that, although unsure how to do that unfortunately :/

Comment: Well there are multiple tasks in there, so tackle each bit individually. Start with using Javascript to send the necessary data. You can get the selected values of each of your form fields (dropdowns and selects) and put them into the payload object in the same kind of way as the existing `"message": document.querySelector(".message").value` code does. If you're not familiar with this aspect of JavaScript, now would be a great time to learn about querySelector etc, and you can easily google and find tutorials/examples showing you how to get the selected value of a radio button etc using JS.

Comment: (P.S. I'm suggesting this so you can make an attempt and learn what's needed in order to attempt to complete the tasks you need to do. If you get stuck on your actual attempt at any of them, you can ask specifically about that. Each of the things I've listed, separately, are actually pretty standard and straightforward things to do which you can research and learn about quite easily - adding extra parameters to a PHP function call is trivial, for instance). Stackoverflow _isn't_ a free write-my-code or tutorial service. We provide answers where necessary, to interesting / new coding challenges